# How to convert a .npz format to .csv in python?

Tags: python, numpy, export-to-csv

I'm new to python. I want to convert a [.npz file](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html) (.npz is a numpy file format) to .csv file to use it in R. Please suggest a way

Answer (score 10):

Try something like:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.load(filename)
for key, value in data.items():
    np.savetxt("somepath" + key + ".csv", value)
```

Comment: What about the other way around, from .csv to .nyz?

Comment: [np.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) and [np.savez](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) would be the keywords to look for

Comment: I found that ```np.load(filename)``` was needed; .loadz wasn't found.